# Bing Maps Force MapIcon to always show

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. The main focus of this app is to provide a birdseye view of incidents on the road.
Since it's a Windows Phone App I decided Bing Maps was my only option.

I'm using the `MapIcon` class to display the incidents on the road.
However just as the documentation says:

> The MapIcon is not guaranteed to be shown. It may be hidden when it
>   obscures other elements or labels on the map.

My Markers only appear when almost zoomed in at max.

I tried working with dedicated `XAML UserControls` but this messes up the reponsiveness of the markers A LOT!
When I manipulate the map the icons are very shaky. It is not like `MapIcon`, that is always in the exact location.

How can I  have a `MapIcon` that will always be visible? Can I define some hierarchy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible (yet). The safe only option for you is to use XAML elements which are - as you already pointed out - guaranteed to be shown.

However there are couple of things you could try in order to get your MapIcon to work / increase your app's performance:

- Depending on the complexity of your map icon: why not **draw** the MapIcon as a composition of MapPolygons and Polylines? It's almost like vector graphics. Just keep in mind that the MapControl will **not** render polygons with holes or self-overlapping polygons.
- Only display XAML elments when necessary. Use `IsLocationInView()` extensively. Avoid unnecessary manipulations at all cost.
- There is another interesting topic on the performance question here: [How to improve Windows Phone 8 Map control performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231758/how-to-improve-windows-phone-8-map-control-performance)

Comment: This is a beginning, but not a solution that satisfies my needs for my application. It's simply too slow and frankly a dirty hack this should be natively supported. Microsoft needs to improve their platform to draw more developers. Start by providing a solid Map solution, Markers that are visible on a map at all times and a buld in click event handler. This is utterly ridiculous.
Sorry for the rant.

Comment: Well, sorry for you. But this is the answer to your question. I've also written several apps with MapControls myself and I know about the struggle. It can only get better ;)

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it is the answer to my question. Thanks for the trouble man.